# My app has been reject by Console Playstore on ANDROID TV version, because "according to them" is not navigable using a 5-way D-pad controller

Tags: xml, apk, google-play-console, google-developers-console, android-app-bundle

My app (aab) has been accepted on the original playstore, but has been reject by Console Playstore FOR **ANDROID TV** version, because "according to them" is not navigable using a 5-way D-pad controller, but in the practice, IS WORKING the D-pad controller.

[The email that they send me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhuLx.png)

I need help, really my acknowledgement is too poor, A friend make me this apk, and I only change icons files, images, and some translation, any can helpme and fix my problem please, i share my apk for download: https://app.skybox.mx and here a testline for test correctly:  username: playconsole1  / password: playconsole2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please share your Android Manfiest

Comment: @ArslanCb https://pastebin.pl/view/03c2e4b4  <-- there my manifiest

Comment: @ArslanCb  i will always grateful with you if you can help me :c

Answer (score 0):

Please note: I wasted almost 3 - 4 months to fully understand the review process and will try my best to save yours.

First thing: You need to be patient.

Step 1
in Android Manifest for Features

(I think lean-back is false in your android manifest)

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
    
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

<!-- Optional -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.type.television"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Step 2 in your Android Manifest for Layouts, set proper screen orientation

```
<activity android:name="your.activity.name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Step 3

You have to make sure, that your app, nowhere has 4:3 Full-screen. We previously faced that there was A video that had first introductory frame in 4:3 and hence there was a rejection

Step 5

Run your app in TV Emulator or better on ATV (Android TV and Not Chinese Android box) and confirm all your controls are working. It's essential that you verify all buttons.

NOTE : If this still does not solve the problem, kindly share a Loom recorded video of your app with navigation and I will update my answer.